# How do I fix the problem on my Nikon D3400 saying "lens not attached" for a Vivitar series 1 500 mm manual Telephoto lens?

Tags: nikon, lens-mount, telephoto, vivitar, nikon-d3400

I just bought a Nikon D3400 and it came with a kit including the Vivitar* (series 1) 500mm f/8 telephoto lens. I expected it to attach and work immediately, but the t mount adapter* for the lens attached it physically but not electronically it also said "lens not attached in all modes except manual. Is it the mount, the lens itself, the camera, or am I doing something wrong? please help.

*These are reference photos of each product- (Lens and mount, Nikon lens attachment)
[image: Vivitar lens]

[image: Vivitar T mount for Nikon]

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to "fix". This lens has no electrical connections to be made to the Nikon D3400.

Because there's no electrical connections to be made, the camera doesn't even know there's a lens attached, or determine the type of lens attached. Thus, you have to set your camera to Manual exposure mode, and set ISO, aperture, and shutter speed yourself — the camera has no way of controlling the lens's aperture, or of knowing what aperture the lens is set to.

Nikon doesn't sell any camera kits with 3rd party lenses such as this Vivitar lens. This lens + camera kit sounds like was a Nikon reseller's bundling.

So no, you're not doing anything wrong, *per se*. You just have more expectations than your lens + camera body can deliver on.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful and informative information if it helps  for explanation whenever I take a photo with this lens attachment the shutter triggers and settings have been changed, but the end photo comes out as a pitch black frame( you can see its put in jpeg and the date it was taken yet. the whole screen is black).

Comment: @craigclark What were you trying to take a picture of (i.e., what were the lighting conditions)? And what were your exposure settings (i.e., ISO, aperture, shutter speed)?

Comment: I don't remember the exact settings. I think I used an iso around the 12800 mark, f/8 aperture, and maybe shutter speed above 1/250 mark and below 1/300 mark. It was a sunny day in my open backyard I was attempting to photograph a redwood post silhouette on a medium blue shed

Answer (score -2):

The Nikon D3400 is a F-Mount body. Looks like you will need an adapter.

Something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Vello-Lens-Mount-Adapter-Camera/dp/B0085MS5G6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0085MS5G6)

Comment: The kit already includes a T-mount adapter. How will a T-mount adapter solve the OP's question about the camera not recognizing a lens that doesn't have any electrical connections?